# Enable apex sharing reason

Tags: apex-sharing

The apex sharing reason related list is absent in the object setting page. How to enable apex sharing reason in a sandbox. This is a detail object in a master detail relationship. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make sobject private. Set your Sobject OWD to private .. is your sobject private?

Comment: @Ratan. The sobject is a detail in MD. The parent is set to private OWD. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: is your parent object (MD)   apex sharing enabled?

Comment: The parent object is account. How do we check for that? Thanks

Comment: So I believe since your Account is private and your custom object controlled by Account... So if you share the Account record with any User.. Then all the related records related to that  Account will be automatic shared with that user.. I believe that's the reason apex sharing not available.  Wait for other response  what's there thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Account is private and your custom object controlled by Account... So if you share the Account record with any User.. Then all the related records related to that Account will be automatic shared with that user.. I believe that's the reason apex sharing not available.

Comment: Yeah Ratan you are correct, the detail records sharing is controlled completely by parent. Hence no share tables.

Comment: @Stygon Yes my assumption is correct.. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Stygon my pleasure..